# Any guides to solve involving graph theory?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

OK. My problem is that I don't know *when* to use the different graph theory algorithms, if it weren't stated in the problem. How do I know when I would use a Prim's/Kruskal's rather than a Floyd/Dijkstra? What specific clues in a problem do would give clues as to what I need to solve? Sorry if this seems like a dumb question, but I know these algorithms (but I haven't implemented much of them, but I'm trying to, like right now! Haha), but I don't seem to know how to use them more practically other than by theory.

Please give tips! (If you need sample problems, or whatever, I'll probably link stuff I find in onlinejudge)

Comment: I think you first need to understand the difference between a shortest path and a minimum spanning tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your basics correct. Know the difference between a MST and Shortest Path. Know what connectivity etc is. The next part of knowing when to apply which algorithm to problems which do not explicitly mention it, comes with practice.

See these tutorials, http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=alg_index
especially the ones in Introduction to Graphs and Their Data Structures.

Then practice some problems on codechef and topcoder. At the end of the day you need to practice, practice and then practice some more.

Comment: Well you don't need to write actual code to learn algorithms. You can also practice with paper and stencil. I find it the fastest way.

Comment: That is probably the best way, the only condition being you should check for its correctness. With problems that don't have a solution proving your method is correct might not be very trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess I'm just being lazy to actually understand the matter, and went on trying to implement them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem that you have reduced to a graph theory problem you should also know what you want to do with it.

If you need to find the shortest path between two points, then you need to use one of the many shortest paths algorithms.

If you need to find a way to match tasks to workers, then you are probably going to reduce this to a max flow problem and use a max flow algorithm to solve it.

I'm not sure I can help you tell the difference between a shortest path problem and a max flow problem, but if you only need to know which algorithm to use then it's simple: It doesn't matter. As long as you pick one of the minimum spanning tree algorithms to solve a minimum spanning tree problem you will come out with a minimum spanning tree.

Look at what the question asks you to find in terms of graph theory, think about how you would logically go about it and choose an algorithm that matches that process and result.